# Is it possible to tag a Facebook Page in a photo and have them appear on the Page timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

When I post pictures to my personal account and tag a Facebook Page in them, they don't show up on the Page's timelime, only if you click through to see the Page's photos.

All the Page settings are as permissive as I can see to allow them.

Is there any way to make this happen?